# Query performance with OR

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Maybe this is a basic question, but haven't been able to answer it, and would appreciate your help :)

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
create table anotation
    ( 
        chromosome enum
            (
                'Chr1',
                'Chr2',
                'Chr3',
                'Chr4',
                'Chr5',
                'ChrC',
                'ChrM'
            ), 
        version varchar(10),
        type enum
            (
                'CDS',
                'chromosome',
                'exon',
                'five_prime_UTR',
                'gene',
                'mRNA',
                'mRNA_TE_gene',
                'miRNA',
                'ncRNA',
                'protein',
                'pseudogene',
                'pseudogenic_exon',
                'pseudogenic_transcript',
                'rRNA',
                'snRNA',
                'snoRNA',
                'tRNA',
                'three_prime_UTR',
                'transposable_element_gene'
            ), 
        strand enum
            (
                 '+',
                 '-'
            ), 
        phase tinyint, 
        atrributes text
    );`
```

And it has around 600,000 values, and I'm doing the following query:

```
select distinct
            anot_1.chromosome,
            anot_1.start,
            anot_1.end,
            anot_1.atrributes 
    from 
            anotation anot_1,
            anotation anot_2 
    where
            anot_1.type='CDS'
        and
            anot_2.type='protein'
        and 
            anot_1.chromosome!='ChrM'
        and
            anot_1.chromosome!='ChrC'
        and
            anot_1.chromosome=anot_2.chromosome
        and 
        (
            (
                anot_2.start=anot_1.start
            and
                anot_1.end!=anot_2.end
            and
                anot_2.strand='+'
            ) 
        or 
            (
                anot_2.start!=anot_1.start
            and
                anot_1.end=anot_2.end
            and
                anot_2.strand='-'
            )
        );
```

And in it takes a long while to finish, acutally, but when I do the query (same one, but I drop the one of the conditions from the OR ) it runs almost instantely:

```
select distinct
            anot_1.chromosome,
            anot_1.start,
            anot_1.end,
            anot_1.atrributes
    from
            anotation anot_1, 
            anotation anot_2
    where
            anot_1.type='CDS'
        and 
            anot_2.type='protein'
        and 
            anot_1.chromosome!='ChrM'
        and
            anot_1.chromosome!='ChrC'
        and
            anot_1.chromosome=anot_2.chromosome
        and
            anot_2.start=anot_1.start
        and
            anot_1.end!=anot_2.end
        and 
            anot_2.strand='+';`
```

Anyone has any idea of whats happening and if so, how can I solve it?
Thank you!!!

Comment: It would help if you simplified the query a little (remove all crud that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem) and format your SQL in a tidy and organized manner so that the small differences between the queries are more obvious.

Comment: Can you post the results of EXPLAIN? 

(Just add EXPLAIN to the start of the query, like EXPLAIN SELECT...)

Comment: Have you added any indexes?

Comment: Out of interest, how many results do you get with the OR compared to the reduced query - perhaps you are just query a much larger set? *you should still be able to make this run quickly though)

Comment: Yes, I've added indexes to start, end, type and chromosome.

Comment: Another thing to try: rather than using OR, you can effectively duplicate the query and UNION the two result sets. Do you still get an immediate result?

Comment: explain of first one:id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE anot_2 ref start,start_2,start_3,end,chromosome,type type 2 const 67950 Using where; Using temporary
1 SIMPLE anot_1 ref start,start_2,start_3,end,chromosome,type chromosome 2 thaliana.anot_2.chromosome 2978 Using where

Comment: Actually, if could you also do: SHOW INDEX FROM mytable

Comment: Yeah UNION runs instantely as well, thats what ive been using so far, but would like to understand why th or is making thigs weird.

Comment: `Table   Non_unique      Key_name        Seq_in_index    Column_name     Collation       Cardinality     Sub_part        Packed  Null    Index_type      Comment Index_commentanotation       1       end     1       end     A       596393  NULL    NULL    YES     BTREE           
anotation       1       chromosome      1       chromosome      A       14      NULL    NULL    YES     BTREE           
anotation       1       type    1       type    A       14      NULL    NULL    YES     BTREE           
anotation       1       start   1       start   A       202     NULL    NULL    YES     BTREE `

Comment: So, this bit `anot_2.start!=anot_1.start and anot_1.end=anot_2.end and anot_2.strand='-'` is the problem?

Comment: It's probably because that query is causing the query plan to change, and not use the indexes you have correctly.

Comment: I forgot to mention, queries with either condition of the OR clause run smoothly, if I separate the query into 2 different queries (each one witht he different part of the OR clause) and then use UNION it runs instantely as well.

Comment: @jodrell well, that part alone works reat, or the other one alone as well, when I use the OR is when i get the huge performance drop

Comment: It's worth noting that the query will only be able to use a single index per table, so you may want to consider using composite indexes with multiple keys (if this makes sense for the data set)

Comment: The problem is in this  anot_2.start!=anot_1.start, make sure that it comes last in your where clause, and indexed differently. Not equal predicate is query killer, because of it is scanning whole table to make sure that there is no value equal, so you need to check it last in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution (and I agree with comments above about indexes), but I have changed your SQL around to use a pair of left outer joins rather than your current SQL which has an OR in the JOIN.

While I don't expect this to be much different in performance it might help you and others see what the query is doing:-

```
SELECT distinct anot_1.chromosome, anot_1.start, anot_1.end, anot_1.atrributes 
FROM anotation anot_1,
LEFT OUTER JOIN anotation anot_2 ON anot_1.chromosome = anot_2.chromosome AND anot_1.start = anot_2.start AND anot_1.end != anot_2.end AND anot_2.strAND = '+' AND anot_2.type='protein'
LEFT OUTER JOIN anotation anot_3 ON anot_1.chromosome = anot_3.chromosome AND anot_1.end = anot_3.end AND anot_1.start != anot_3.start AND anot_3.strAND = '+' AND anot_3.type='protein'
WHERE anot_1.type = 'CDS'  
AND anot_1.chromosome != 'ChrM' 
AND anot_1.chromosome != 'ChrC' 
AND (anot_2.chromosome IS NOT NULL
OR anot_3.chromosome IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by sanitising your query in general, breaking them apart and doing a union

```
select
            CDS.chromosome,
            CDS.start,
            CDS.end,
            CDS.atrributes 
    from
            (
            select
                        a.chromosome,
                        a.start,
                        a.end,
                        a.attribures,
                from
                        anotation a,
                where
                        a.type='CDS'
                    and
                        not a.chromosome IN ('ChrM', 'ChrC')
            ) CDS
        join
            (
            select
                        a.strand,
                from
                        anotation a,
                where
                        a.type='protien'
            ) Protien
                on 
                        CDS.chromosome = Protien.chromosome
                   and
                        CDS.start = Protien.start
                   and
                        CDS.end != Protien.end 
where
            Protien.strand = '+'
union
    select
            CDS.chromosome,
            CDS.start,
            CDS.end,
            CDS.atrributes 
    from
            (
            select
                        a.chromosome,
                        a.start,
                        a.end,
                        a.attribures,
                from
                        anotation a,
                where
                        a.type='CDS'
                    and
                        not a.chromosome IN ('ChrM', 'ChrC')
            ) CDS
        join
            (
            select
                        a.strand,
                from
                        anotation a,
                where
                        a.type='protien'
            ) Protien
                on 
                        CDS.chromosome = Protien.chromosome
                   and
                        CDS.start != Protien.start
                   and
                        CDS.end = Protien.end 
where
            Protien.strand = '-'
```

Comment: First of all, thnx for the edits, next time ill paste my code in that format. Yeah, as I said the join works great, that is what I've been using. But what I'm asking is why is the OR having a performance problem, while the simple queries work great.

Comment: @JorgeKageyama, I think essentially, its hard for the engine to distinguish and optimize for the best criteria when your conditions work on two inverted sets that are not clearly distinguished. Especially when the join conditions are intermingled with the limits of the query. The query optimization process is not magic and its good if we can give it the right kind of help.